# Allow indexing a PDF in the directory of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, robots.txt, magento2.2

I want to allow the indexing of a pdf page in Magento 2 directory, I navigate to content-> Configuration -> Edit (first row)

Under search engine robots -> Edit custom instruction of robots.txt File, I have the following:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: example.com/sitemap.xml
```

If the PDF name is: 2018-document.pdf, how can I add it to the above so that I have it along with the sitemap?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (and you can't) add a PDF reference in the `robots.txt`. You should include a link to it in your `sitemap.xml`.